# Why is the path found by my call to CMake's find_library command wrong?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to include a library in my CMakeLists.txt
Doing it like i have doe works on other machines but on this one the found path is wrong.

Snippet from my CMake:

```
message("Host system: ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
if (CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "aarch64")
  find_library(libCubeEye NAMES libCubeEye.so HINTS thirdparty/aarch64/libcubeeye/lib/)
elseif(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "x86_64")
  if(UNIX)
    find_library(libCubeEye NAMES libCubeEye.so HINTS thirdparty/x86_64/libcubeeye/lib)
  endif(UNIX)
  if(WIN32)
    find_library(libCubeEye NAMES libCubeEye.lib HINTS thirdparty/x86_64/libcubeeye/lib)
  endif(WIN32)
endif()
message(${libCubeEye})

if (NOT libCubeEye)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "libCubeEye library not found")
endif()
```

The system i am working on is x86_64, but the found path is:
`/home/path_to_my_src/thirdparty/libcubeeye/lib/libCubeEye.so`
when it should look like this:
`/home/path_to_my_src/thirdparty/x86_64/libcubeeye/lib/libCubeEye.so`
Meaning the CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR is excluded.
Also the directory it finds dose NOT exist.

Additionally when i try to make i get the error:
`*** No rule to make 'thirdparty/libcubeeye/lib/libCubeEye.so', needed by 'bin/main'. Stop.`
Which makes sense give the wrong path it finds

Comment: Have you tried to clear the CMake cache before re-configuring? Result of `find_library` is stored in the cache, so following running of `cmake` doesn't rewrite that result even if stored path is no longer valid.

Comment: Yes, i did a 'make clean' before running cmake

Comment: No, `make clean` isn't the same as clearing CMake's cache. You need to delete `CMakeCache.txt` in your build directory.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to caching and things having moved around since the last cache value was persisted.

The result of calls to functions like [`find_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_file.html), [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html), [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html), [`find_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html), and [`find_program`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html) cache the result of what they find in the CMake Cache (the CMakeCache.txt file in the build directory) (probably for performance optimization reasons). If you want to read in depth about the variable cache in CMake, see [the corresponding chapter of "Mastering CMake"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/CMake%20Cache.html) and [the brief section on cache variables in the CMake language reference docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables). All of those commands except `find_package` accept a `NO_CACHE` argument to prevent caching.

Running a "clean build" command has no(?) effect on the CMake cache. If you want to edit the cache, you can either rerun configuration with [`--fresh`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-fresh) (if you have CMake 3.24+ installed), or if you want to manually edit the cached variable, you can use a cache editor program like one of the bundled [interactive dialogues](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/#interactive-dialogs) (after which you will need to rerun configuration to generate a buildsystem based on the updated cache variables).